# jQuery $.each() not working on object as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following object:

```
var objectVar = {
    4 : { "key" : "key-name4", "item4" : {} },
    3 : { "key" : "key-name3", "item3" : {} }
}
```

I then try the following:

```
$(objectVar).each(function(index,record){
    console.log(record); // Loops Only Once and Logs Full Object
});
```

Can anyone help me with why the `$.each();` function inst iterating through the sub objects within the main object?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> *"Can anyone help me with why the $.each(); function inst iterating through the sub objects within the main object?"*

To loop the sub objects, you need sub loops.

While using the [`each()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method  like you have will <s>usually</s> sometimes work <s>(as it currently is)</s>, it is really meant for DOM elements.

Instead use the [`jQuery.each()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method:

```
$.each( objectVar, function(index,record){
    console.log(record); 

      // start a loop on the current record in the iteration
    $.each( record, function( index2, sub_record ) {
        console.log( index2, sub_record );
    });
});
```

Now your looping will be extended to the first level of nested objects.

If you're not sure of the overall structure, and want to enumerate the entire depth, you'll need to test each value encountered to see if it should be enumerated.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! I know its outside the scope of the OP, but do you know if there is a way to get the each() function to parse in order of the numbered keys instead of the order the records appear inside the object?

Comment: @dSquared: No, there isn't really any way to do that with an object. The only way would be to define an Array that describes the order you want, then iterate the Array, and fetch the related item from the object. So if your object has keys `7,3,9,4`, you could create an Array `arr=[3,4,7,9]` to define the order, then iterate the Array, and do `objectVar[ arr[i] ]`. But that gets a little complicated.

Comment: ...to get sequential ordering of numeric keys, you should really use an Array in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method instead of the [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method:

```
$.each(objectVar, function(index, record) {
  console.log(record);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

While jQuery is great, you really aren't using it. JavaScript looping through objects is fairly simple as is:

```
var record;
for(var key in objectVar) {
    record = objectVar[key];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$.each(objectVar,function(index,record){
    console.log(record);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `$.each()` incorrectly for non-jQuery objects:

```
$.each( objectVar, function( index, record ){
    console.log( record );
});
```

[jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)